# S Parameters Channel Modelling Time domain representation of insertion loss

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave, signal-integrity, s-parameters

Below is the insertion loss waveform obtained after S parameter of a channel.The waveform is in frequency domain.

May I know what is the equivalent time domain waveform and how to obtain it from this frequency domain waveform.

[image: INSERTION LOSS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> May I know what is the equivalent time domain waveform and how to obtain it from this frequency domain waveform.

No, you may not!

What you see is an absolute value of the loss, not something that contains a phase. So, you can't reconstruct the time-domain waveform from that at all.

Besides, this is not a "frequency domain signal" in the sense that it's the result of a Fourier transform applied to a time-domain signal; it's a plotting of incoherently observed losses at different frequencies. So, the signal you think exist really doesn't.

Comment: Thank you Muller. If we take inverse Fourier transform of the above signal will we get time domain waveform.

Comment: Please read my answer, it's quite explicit on that; thank you!

Comment: sure,thank you.

Comment: The original S parameter data should include both amplitude and phase, or both real and imaginary though.

Comment: @Steve absolutely; if you had phase information (equivalent to complex values) you could, to some degree (assuming things were sampled finely enough in frequency), reconstruct the channel's impulse response – which is still a *system*, not a *signal* (but that might be mincing words)